# How To display Snowpark Stored Procedure Logs in standard output?

Tags: python, logging, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Snowflake wants me to do some configuration to be able to store logging outputs but I am not interested in that feature at the moment. All I would like to do is see some info statements in the terminal.

Per Snowflake you can add logging statements like so...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE do_logging()
RETURNS VARCHAR
LANGUAGE PYTHON
PACKAGES=('snowflake-snowpark-python')
RUNTIME_VERSION=3.8
HANDLER='do_things'
AS $$
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger("python_logger")
logger.info("Logging from Python module.")

def do_things(session):
  logger.info("Logging from Python function start.")

  try:
    throw_exception()
  except Exception:
    logger.error("Logging an error from Python handler: ")
    return "ERROR"

  return "SUCCESS"

def throw_exception():
  raise Exception("Something went wrong.")

$$;
```

How do I display these in the terminal when I call this function? I have tried including `logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stdout, level=logging.INFO)` and it works locally but not when called as a stored procedure.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE do_logging()
RETURNS VARCHAR
LANGUAGE PYTHON
PACKAGES=('snowflake-snowpark-python')
RUNTIME_VERSION=3.8
HANDLER='do_things'
AS $$
import sys
import logging

logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stdout, level=logging.INFO)

logger = logging.getLogger("python_logger")
logger.info("Logging from Python module.")

def do_things(session):
  logger.info("Logging from Python function start.")
```

[Snowflake Documentation](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/logging-tracing/logging-python)

Answer (score 3):

Snowflake stored procedures execute in a controlled environment within the Snowflake cloud, and their execution does not directly communicate with your local terminal. To see the logs, you need to set an event table that you can query. You can do this by following the instructions at: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/logging-tracing/event-table-setting-up